# Teams in North American leagues that won their first game ever?

Tags: trivia, history, major-leagues

**What teams, in the four major North American leagues (NHL, NBA, NFL, MLB), won their first ever game?**

This includes both expansion franchises (e.g., Minnesota Wild) and relocations (e.g., Atlanta Thrashers -> Winnipeg Jets, Seattle SuperSonics -> Oklahoma City Thunder).

I take it is easier for recent additions or relocations, but it is somewhat harder to determine, for example, if the Ottawa Senators of the NHL won their first ever game, in 1917, the year the original team joined the NHL.

This is what I have figured out so far:

## NBA

- Vancouver Grizzlies (beat the Portland TrailBlazers 92-80 on Nov 3, 1995)
- Toronto Raptors (beat the New Jersey Nets 94-79 on Nov 3, 1995)

## NHL

- Colorado Avalanche (beat the Detroit Red Wings 3-2 on Oct 6, 1995)
- Atlanta Flames (beat the NY Islanders 3-2 on Oct 7, 1972)
- Dallas Stars (beat the Detroit Red Wings 6-4 on Oct 5, 1993)

## MLB

- Montreal Expos (beat the NY Mets 11-10 on Apr 8, 1969)

## NFL

- Houston Texans (beat the Dallas Cowboys 19-10 on Sep 8, 2002)

Comment: As with other list type questions, this is a bad fit for Stack Exchange's Q&A format.

Comment: I don't see how a question like this can be "too broad" or even "off topic". I've added as many details I could.

Comment: The trouble with list type questions is that there isn't going to be one, or even a few, good answers to the question, so they don't fit well into Stack Exchange's Q&A format. The answer you received on this question demonstrates this pretty well: when another 10 people find instances, they add their own answer. Now we've got ten answers, none of which are really any better than the other. A good SE answer should stand alone, without needing reference to other answers, and experience has shown that doesn't happen for list-type questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can count their first appearance being an exhibition game, the Orlando Magic won their first ever appearance against the Detroit Pistons in 1989.